# Cordova Camera Plugin Crash iOS - r0.3.5

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am facing issue with org.apache.cordova.camera r0.3.5 on iOS. Everything works fine for me with r0.3.4. The app crashes as soon as I try to take a picture. Please see the line where it is causing the problem.

```
- (void)takePicture:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
  ....
  [weakSelf.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:^
Thread 3: EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
}

2015-02-27 09:28:50.332 App[1455:860f] bool
_WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1ee707a0: Tried to obtain the web lock from 
a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a 
result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x39e643b7 WebThreadLock
2   0x35fc5b4f <redacted>
3   0x35e01691 <redacted>
4   0x36042619 <redacted>
5   0x35e549b9 <redacted>
6   0x35e52fe7 <redacted>
7   0x21d93 __25-[CDVCamera takePicture:]_block_invoke
8   0x3bfd311f <redacted>
9   0x3bfe1259 <redacted>
10  0x3bfe13b9 <redacted>
11  0x3c007a11 <redacted>
12  0x3c0078a4 start_wqthread
```

Thanks,

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same issue. I debugged it a bit and the problem was with CDVCamera.m file. At line 170 you have the following code

```
[weakSelf.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:^{
    weakSelf.hasPendingOperation = NO;
}];
```

This entire call should be dispatched in the main thread. I assume this is fixed in the later version but if you want a quick fix just do the following

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakSelf.viewController presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:^{
         weakSelf.hasPendingOperation = NO;
    }];
});
```

So in short either you can go for the new version i.e. r0.3.6 or you can change this yourself. Just in case you don't know you will find this file in the plugins folder under the "org.apache.cordova.camera" folder. Cheers !!